# Linear encoder with webcam to measure length

Tags: c#, vb.net, image-processing, video, webcam

There are tools like digital caliper, linear encoders that measures lengths. the are basically rulers and they use magnetic strips. they simply count magnetic stripes and calculated the distance.

I want to make it optical by using webcam instead of using magnetic stripes.

Imagine a ruler with webcam pointed on it. dont think about numbers or anything. just imagine ruler with vertical lines. webcam placed to this ruler very closely and image is very clear.

as webcam moves, vertical lines will travel across video.

what I want to do is count these lines at the center of the video so I can calculate how far we go.

I googled every word I can think of to find a stating point I had no luck.

any suggestions please ? I need to use windows platform for this project. c# or vbnet are wellcome.

best...

Comment: What you are suggesting is a basic form of [Machine Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_vision), you will need a far higher resolution and higher quality optics than a webcam can provide to measure accurately.

Comment: The [Video Content Analysis Wikipedia entry](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_content_analysis) has plenty of keywords to get your search started.

Comment: If you want to count lines and work with C# I suggest Hough-Transform and Aforge.NET or EMGUCV as Keywords for your search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this; it's not been updated in a while but the concepts are all there.

http://reprap.org/wiki/CamRap

Comment: Please replicate the answer here.